# Using scanner various times in a loop Java

Tags: java

I'm new in this, i'm trying to write a code which stores user input in a array of *n* length (the length is also decided by the user).
So I decided to use a `while` loop to use `Scanner` *n* times, so that each time the user could store an `String` in that location as the loop advances.

But when I run the code, it just prints the statements don't letting me (or the user) to input the `String`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] contadores;

        Scanner cont= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the length of the array + 1: ");
        int cuenta = cont.nextInt();
     // Thread.sleep(4000);
        contadores = new String[cuenta];

        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i=0;
        while (i<= (contadores.length-1)) {
            System.out.println("Input the word in the space: "+(i));
            String libro = d.toString();

            contadores[i] = libro;
            i++;
        }
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
Input the length of the array + 1: 
3
Input the word in the space: 0
Input the word in the space: 1
Input the word in the space: 2
```

As you see it doesn't give me enough time to input something, I don't know if it JDK (I think not), or it is because is inside the `main`, I tried using `Thread.sleep(4000);` but the output is an error `Unhandled exception type InterruptedException`.

Comment: use the same `Scanner` var, don't need to create a new one `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not scanning inside the `while` loop. You need to scan the words the way you have scanned the integer. Instead of using `d.next()`, you've used `d.toString()`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] contadores;

        Scanner cont = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the length of the array: ");
        int cuenta = cont.nextInt();
        contadores = new String[cuenta];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < contadores.length) {
            System.out.print("Input the word for the index " + (i) + ": ");
            String libro = cont.next();
            contadores[i] = libro;
            i++;
        }

        // Display the array
        for (String s : contadores) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Input the length of the array: 4
Input the word for the index 0: Hello
Input the word for the index 1: World
Input the word for the index 2: Good
Input the word for the index 3: Morning
Hello
World
Good
Morning
```

Also, note that I've used only one instance of `Scanner`. You do not need two instances of `Scanner`. You can reuse the same instance of `Scanner` everywhere in your program.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, if you have some literature about why .next() worked and .toString() didn't in this case it would pretty helpful. I think is something about "eating" and \n space. But its not pretty clear for me.

Comment: @josefisa - I missed your comment. The method, [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is a method from [the default superclass of every Java class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and it returns a `String` rather than blocking and waiting for input to scan, the way [Scanner::next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) does. I hope, it helps.